Como puedo compilar el fmx de oracle form mediante un boton programable
Necesito crear un fmb de oracle y quiero ejecutar el compilado del objeto (fmx) mediante un boton programable, como puedo declarar el codigo, existira uno?
Muchas gracias por sus conocimientos, un abrazo!

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
